# Haskell: can't use "map putStrLn"?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I have a list of strings, and tried this:

```
ls = [ "banana", "mango", "orange" ]

main = do
       map PutStrLn list_of_strings
```

That didn't work, and I can't understand why.

```
ghc print-list.hs
print-list.hs:3:0:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO t' against inferred type `[IO ()]'
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the function `main'
```

Any hints? I suppose it has to do with map returning a list and not a value, but I didn't find an easy way to fix this.

Right now the only way I know to print a list of strings is to write a function that will iterate the list, printing each element (print if the list is [a], but print and recurse if it's (a:b)). But it would be *much* simpler to just use map...

Thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The type of the `main` function should be `IO t` (where `t` is a type variable). The type of `map putStrLn ls` is `[IO ()]`. This why you are getting this error message. You can verify this yourself by running the following in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :type map putStrLn ls
map putStrLn ls :: [IO ()]
```

One solution to the problem is using [`mapM`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3AmapM), which is the "monadic" version of `map`. Or you can use [`mapM_`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3AmapM_) which is the same as `mapM` but does not collect the returned values from the function. Since you don't care about the return value of `putStrLn`, it's more appropriate to use `mapM_` here. `mapM_` has the following type:

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

Here is how to use it:

```
ls = [ "banana", "mango", "orange" ]
main = mapM_ putStrLn ls
```

Comment: Something that I wish I'd learned a lot sooner was that there's another mapM defined in Data.Traversable.  This mapM works more data structures in addition to lists, such as maps and arrays.

Comment: I always thought that `main` should be of type `IO ()`, never knew it could be `forall t. IO t`. That shows how you can learn something new each day :-)

Comment: I have an `IO String` and I want to map it to `IO Int` and print the `Int`. How do I do it in _one_ line? Is that possible.

Answer (score 23):

Ayman's answer makes most sense for this situation. In general, if you have `[m ()]` and you want `m ()`, then use `sequence_`, where `m` can be any monad including `IO`.