# howto print each element of a [String] with putStrLn in a function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to print a list of strings like `["hallo", "world", "!"]` using putStrLn so that I get the output:

```
hello
world
!
```

How can I do this with a function? I have

```
printMe :: [String] -> String
printMe (x:xs) =
```

but don't know what to do from here

Comment: Do you want to print the result or return it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the general tools of Haskell libraries. This version returns the concatenated string for you to print out in a more appropriate place.

```
 printMe xs = foldr (++) "" (map (\str -> str ++ "\n") xs)
```

Or you can print it right away by a simpler mapping:

```
 printMeM xs = mapM_ putStrLn xs
```

This is very rude because I'm not really a Haskell programmer yet.

Comment: @progo - Nevertheless, your answer is valid. Go ahead!

Comment: @Ingo, thanks, yeah I tested it okay. But the code isn't very pretty :(

Comment: @progo - Well, the 1st one is a bit overkill. How about fold (++) "" (intersperse "\n" xs)

Comment: `concat` is clearer than `foldr (++) ""` but means the same thing.

Comment: @progo Another tip: look up `unlines` :)

Comment: @Ingo, `intersperse` won't add a final terminating newline.  @progo, `mapM_ putStrLn` is the idiomatic way to do this, good answer :-)

Comment: `unlines` is good, but I'm surprised nobody has mentioned `concatMap` yet.

Comment: @luqui - this is fine as he uses printStrLn anyway.

Comment: "I'm not really a Haskell programmer yet" - consider this your inauguration. Welcome to the club!

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I'm proud to be part of it. :>

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at this answer? [Haskell: can't use "map putStrLn"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932639/haskell-cant-use-map-putstrln)

Answer (score 1):

Completing your example:

```
printMe [] = return ()    -- never forget the base case!
printMe (x:xs) = do
    putStrLn x
    printMe  xs
```

You'll realize, however, that you find yourself typing code that looks like the above again and again, and then you'll like to look at `forM`, `mapM`, `sequence` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
printMe = putStrLn . intercalate ("\n")
```

Note that I used putStrLn instead of putStr in order to get an additional newline after the last word, as intercalate adds the first argument only between the list elements.

Comment: That will also add an additional newline even if there are no words, which I don't think the OP wants.