# Why can't you map print to a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, side-effects

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932639/haskell-cant-use-map-putstrln) post before making this, but that post doesn't really explain *why* this doesn't work.

```
foo :: (Num a, Show a) => a -> IO ()
foo 0 = print "Was zero"
foo x = print x

foo 2 -- prints 2
foo 5 -- prints 5

map foo [0..10] :: [IO ()] -- Doesn't print out numbers.
```

Edit:

```
bar 0 = foo 0
bar n = do
            foo n
            bar (n - 1)
```

I *do* understand why this returns `[IO ()]`, but I don't understand why the printing doesn't occur while building this list. At the very least, I'd expect that we'd see the *first* print call occur because of lazy evaluation.

In the process of creating this list, why isn't the 'side effect' of printing to the screen occurring? Is the `foo` function not actually entered when applied to each element of the list? If the `print` calls are evaluated to get the `IO ()` to build the list, why doesn't the side effect happen?

Comment: Your `foo` function doesn't accept any arguments with this function head.

Comment: Your `bar` function in the edit does not return `[IO ()]`, but rather `IO ()`. It prints all the inputs (when run in GHCI), but its return type is definitely not a list of anything, as you can see by looking at it: there are no lists anywhere!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map foo [0..10]` will definitely construct a list of `IO ()` values, but constructing an `IO ()` value doesn’t execute the `IO`. You probably know this intuitively: if we have a global `IO ()` and nothing referencing it, it doesn’t get executed:

```
sayHello :: IO ()
sayHello = putStrLn "hello"
```

You might attribute that to laziness; after all, if `sayHello` isn’t referenced, nothing ever forces its evaluation. But then, this doesn’t do anything either:

```
main = sayHello `seq` return ()
```

Here, we are *certainly* evaluating `sayHello`, but we’re only evaluating an `IO ()`.

What makes an `IO` do something is when you compose it into another `IO` (like `main`) and *that* gets run, and *only then* will it do something:

```
main = sayHello
```

---

I should note that GHCi clouds the situation a bit. GHCi has some special interactions with `IO`: if the overall expression you type at the prompt yields an `IO`, it will execute it and display the result of that. Otherwise, it just displays the result. But that is just an interactive feature; in real Haskell code, you can’t just have an `IO ()` and expect it to turn into a `()` magically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer- I have started learning Haskell but I have not really gotten to monads or to the internals of `IO`. `print` returns `IO ()`, and I've been reading that as `print returns an action that returns ()`. Is that right? So what you are saying is that it's not the call to `print` that prints `1` to the screen- it's when we evaluate what is returned by print?

Comment: @user2666425: Kind of, but you have to be careful with your wording. Evaluation is pure, and won’t ever *do* anything. On the other hand, *executing* (not merely evaluating) the monadic action returned by `print` does indeed print the `1` to the screen.

Comment: You mention that if GHCi will execute an `IO` if an expression returns one- then why doesn't GHCi execute each `print` when it successively does `map print [1..10]`? `print 1`, `print 2`, etc, are expressions that are yielding a `IO`, right?

Comment: @user2666425: Those are indeed expressions yielding an `IO`, but I was a little sloppy in describing GHCi’s automatic execution. GHCi doesn’t automatically execute *all* `IO` in expressions. The only `IO` it will try to execute is the one wrapping the result of the overall expression you’ve typed in at the prompt, if there is an `IO` at all. It does not modify the evaluation behavior for subexpressions.

Comment: Last question- I've updated my post with `bar`, which calls `foo` and then calls itself. Why does `bar` print out the values then? I thought `do` returns the value of the last expression in it, so why is GHCi executing each `IO ()` returned from `foo` if it's not the top-level expression?

Comment: @user2666425: You’ve been mislead about `do`. `do` is one way you can combine a few monadic values into one big monadic value that does everything inside it. In fact, `do` is just syntactic sugar: the right hand side of your `bar n` could be written as `foo n >> bar (n - 1)`. Looking at the type of `>>`, it takes two monadic values and gives you a new monadic value. So there what you’re doing is recursively building up a big monadic value, and then all GHCi does is execute that, at which point all the effects contained within begin to execute.

Comment: Your last remark about composing things into other things is rather unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> If the `print` calls are evaluated to get the `IO ()` to build the list, why doesn't the side effect happen?

Because evaluating an expression of type `IO ()` doesn't have any side effects. In fact, evaluating an expression of any type doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: Then why does `foo 1` print `1` and return `IO ()`?

Comment: Evaluating `foo 1` doesn't print `1`. Evaluate ``foo 1 `seq` return ()``: it will evaluate `foo 1`, but `1` won't be printed.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to run an `IO` action is to assign it to `main`.  Evaluating `IO` actions does not run them.

If you want to call `print` on the list of values, you must do two things:

First: use `mapM_` to build an `IO` action that `print`s each value:

```
mapM_ print [1..3] :: IO ()
```

Second, assign that expression to `main`:

```
main = mapM_ print [1..3]
```

If you leave out the second step (assign it to something other than `main`), nothing will happen.

Comment: Gracias Gabriel, the `mapM_` helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

In the `IO` monad, something like `IO a` is required. You have `[IO ()]` which is a list of IO operations. You can use `mapM` instead, to do a monadic map. `mapM f` is equivalent to `sequence . map f`.